# Why do big open source PHP projects NOT use MVC?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, open-source

I am curious, why all the larger open source PHP projects, it seems none of them use the MVC pattern and all the post on SO promote it's use?

Comment: give an example to a new system (i.e. was written in the last 3-4 years)

Comment: Can you list some projects you're referring to?

Comment: @Matt phpBB springs to mind, as well as PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: 11 years old and 13 years old -- you're talking about software that was first written before PHP even had decent OO functionality upon which to implement the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

phpBB and PHPMyAdmin, (and PHPlist, SquirrelMail and others) are all very old code-bases originating on PHP3 and PHP4.  They have not been rewritten to use techniques like MVC or even OO in most cases.  PHP coding conventions prior to PHP5 were mainly procedural and it was very common to find application logic inter-mingled with presentation and database logic.

In fact, the PHP language encourages inter-mingling presentation and logic since PHP is itself a templating language.  As the OO support improved, those coding methods are becoming increasingly discouraged.

Newer or rapidly developed code-bases like Drupal, WordPress and the Facebook API do use modern patterns, however.

Comment: MVC was first described in 1979, not very modern in my opinion :)

Comment: The MVC pattern from 1979, describing the interaction of desktop software GUIs with the data they are an interface to, is almost completely unrelated to what we call MVC on the web. You're essentially talking about a different pattern. You also have to take into account that PHP did not exist in 1979, nor did it have the same object oriented framework it has today just 10 years ago, more recently than these packages were written.

Comment: @Karl fair enough :) But PHP coding conventions prior to the early 2000's were decidedly not MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Most of those were already based in nonMVC php, and it worked. Although I am supporter of MVC symfony I can see why they'd changed the codebase to make it MVC.